# How ApplePay payment works?

Tags: applepay

Can anyone explain to me how ApplePay works ?

I have gone through some blogs but I am still unclear about the payment flow.

Questions:

1. How card is added.
2. How Transaction process works.

Answer (score 6):

This is how apple pay works.

**Step 1: Adding a card.**

[image]

**Step 2: Payment using contactless terminal.**

[image]

**Step 3: Final Transection from contactless terminal.**

[image]

You can check this [link.](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/category/mobile-payments/apple-pay/#)

Answer (score -1):

**InApp ApplePay**

Just **high level** diagrams

Who is who:

- Card - card with PAN, Cardholder name, expiration date, CVV/CVC
- Cardholder - **buyer**, person who is an owner of a card
- Merchant - **seller**
- Issuer - **Bank** which supports the Cardholder
- Acquirer - **Bank** which supports the Merchant
- Payment Network - linker of Acquirer and Issuer, e.g. Visa, MasterCard, AmericanExpress...

[image]

Cardholder add a Card to Wallet App:
[image]

Cardholder buy something in an app:
[image]

Some abbreviation:

- Secure Element(SE) - It is a special microprocessor physical chip on device that stores sensitive data
- Primary Account Number (PAN) - card number
- Device Account Number(DAN) - unique PAN representation for device
- Token Service Provider(TSP) - generates and saves Card Data
- Payment Data(PD) typically includes information about the transaction- amount, cardholder name, transaction amount, card expiration date, transaction time...
- TSP Token - id of record with card data information on TSP side
- SE Cryptogram - dynamic representation of private data. It is created every time when new transaction is instantiated
- Transaction is authorised when Issuer approved transaction
- Discount Rate - is a floating percentage(e.g. 2%) of transaction amount of which is set by Payment Network and which is hold and shared between participants - Issuer(1.7%), Acquirer(0.2%), Payment Network(0.1%). Issuer pays Interchange Fee to Apple (1.7% of the Issuer's transaction income)

PKPayment structure:

```
PKPayment                                 - Apple Payment Payload
  token: PKPaymentToken                   - Apple Payment Token
    paymentMethod: PKPaymentMethod 
      displayName: String
      network: PKPaymentNetwork           - Payment Network(visa, masterCard, amex...)
      type: PKPaymentMethodType           - (debit, credit, prepaid...)
      paymentPass: PKPaymentPass
    paymentData: Data                       
      signature                           - deatached signature of version == EC_v1(ephemeralPublicKey, data, transactionId, applicationData), version == RSA_v1(wrappedKey, data, transactionId, applicationData) in PKCS7 to verify
      data                                - Encrypted Payment Data(EPD)
        applicationPrimaryAccountNumber   - DAN
        applicationExpirationDate         - Card expiration date
        currencyCode                      - Currency Code
        transactionAmount                 - Amount
        cardholderName                    - Cardholder Name
        deviceManufacturerIdentifier
        paymentDataType                   - "3DSecure" or "EMV"
        paymentData
          //paymentDataType == 3D Secure
          onlinePaymentCryptogram         - SE Cryptogram   
          eciIndicator

          //paymentDataType == EMV
          emvData
          encryptedPINData
        authenticationResponses
          merchantIdentifier
          authenticationData
          transactionAmount
        merchantTokenIdentifier           - TSP token
        merchantTokenMetadata
      version                             - Apple Pay servers encrypted the payment token(data) 
        EC_v1                             - ECC 
        RSA_v1                            - RSA
      header
        transactionId                     - Transaction Id
        applicationData                   - SHA–256 hash which was swnd in PKPaymentRequest.applicationData
        publicKeyHash                     - SHA–256 hash of Merchant public key
        //version == EC_v1
        ephemeralPublicKey                - Ephemeral public key bytes
        //version == RSA_v1
        wrappedKey                        - Symmetric Key which is decrypted by Merchant public key
  billingAddress
  billingContact
  shippingContact
  shippingAddress
  shippingMethod
```

Verify the Signature:
`PKPayment.PKPaymentToken.Data.signature` is detached PKCS #7 signature[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75592073/4770877) with Intermediate and End-user chain certificates[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59307015/4770877)

Restore the Symmetric Key:

- PKPayment.token.paymentData.data - Encrypted Payment Data is encrypted under a Symmetric Key

//version == EC_v1

- Restoring the Symmetric Key for ECC
- Apple Pay uses Elliptic Curve Diffie–Hellman(ECDH) (id-ecDH 1.3.132.1.12)[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75401377/4770877)

Side Apple:

- Apple generates ephemeral key pair (private/public key) = generate from Merchant ECC Certificate public INFO AND random private key
- Apple Pay computes *shared secret key* = Merchant public key AND ephemeral private key
- KDF(shared secret key, MerchantId) => Symmetric Key

Side Merchant:

- Merchant computes *shared secret key* = Merchant private key AND ephemeral public key
- KDF(shared secret key, MerchantId) => Symmetric Key
- Decrypt the Payment Data by Symmetric Key

[Apple Pay Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/ApplePay_Guide/Authorization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014764-CH4-SW3)
[Payment Token Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/apple_pay/payment_token_format_reference)

[[Encoding vs Encryption vs Hashing]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75401377/4770877)